# Auto labeling environments in AUCTeX

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex

If I insert some environment in AUCTeX by `C-c C-e` (for example `equation` or `figure`) then AUCTeX ask for a label with auto-inserted text `eq:` or `fig:`.

I would like to add `theorem` environment to LaTeX environments in AUCTeX. I done this by

```lisp
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
        (lambda ()
          (LaTeX-add-environments
            '("theorem" LaTeX-env-label)
)))
```

Moreover I hove something like

```lisp
(setq reftex-label-alist
      '(
        ("theorem" ?t "thm:" "~\\ref{%s}" t  ("theorem" "th."))
        ))
```

Then when I use `C-c C-e` to add `theorem` environment then it ask for a label for a theorem but without auto `thm:` text. I need to add this manually.

Is it possible to make AUCTeX add `theorem` environment acts the same as `equation` or `figure` adding auto `thm:` text to a label?

To clarify, if I add `theorem` environment without a label and then use `C-c (` to use RefTeX to add a label then it ask for a label in the form `thm:`.

Comment: have you set `reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX` to `t`?

Comment: @rvf0068: yes, it's turned on.

Comment: @rvf0068 now it works but i think there are still some issues: if you type `theorem` and then press `C-c )`, you can't select them for some reason.

Comment: I can't explain it, but sometimes it helps me to reload the .tex buffer, and to reset AuCTeX (`C-u C-c C-n`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got it.

I was not aware that after adding something like

```lisp
(setq reftex-label-alist
      '(
        ("theorem" ?t "thm:" "~\\ref{%s}" t  ("theorem" "th."))
        ))
```

to my `.emacs` I should do

```
reftex-reset-mode
```

If I put this into `.emacs` after my RefTeX options then everything works great.